# How to change content of elementor widget by code without UI

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming, elementor

I am developing WordPress plugin that can be generated pages with elementor template. After generating pages, I want to change the content of page from plugin without accessing elementor UI.

Pages generating part has been completed.

Now my problem is changing elementor widget content according to plugin settings when submitting plugin settings.

I have gone through the elementor developer documentation and still couldn't find a solution.
Elementor save entire page content in one database row of WordPress database.

IT would be really appreciated if anyone has a solution with this from elementor side or database side.

Comment: If I remember well, my colleague was manipulating DB in the kind of similar scenario.

Comment: What type of contents do you want to generate in the templates?

Comment: I want to add short code to elementor block